# Can't access HTML value using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access the value field in on wolfram website
https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/triple-integral-calculator

I wanted to access each of those 4 fields and copy each to a list in python.
I am struggling at getting to the value.

Here is the HTML picture:
[image]

And here is my code and what I have tried so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/triple-integral-calculator'
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find("div",{"class":"_3hRV6"})
label = content.find("label",{"class":""})
value = content.find("input",{"autocapitalize":"off"})
hint = value.find("id")
print(content)
print(label)
print(value)
print(hint)
```

any help would be appreciated it.

Thank you,
Osmiqa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all 4 values from `<input>` into a list you can use:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/triple-integral-calculator"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

out = [inp["value"] for inp in soup.select("input")]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['x^2 + y^2 + z^2', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! would you mind explaining a bit this line?
`out = [inp["value"] for inp in soup.select("input")]`

also what if I want to print those values individually? The reason why I ask is because this is a dummy test, for another real project where I would need to use that. Thank you again :)

Comment: @Osmiqa `soup.select("input")` will select all `<input>` tags from the HTML document. `[inp["value"] for inp in soup.select("input")]` is a "list comprehension" - it will iterate over all `<input>` tags and stores the `value="..."` attribute in the new  list. To print the values individually, you can do for example: `print(*out, sep='\n')`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It really clears it out.